# What is the difference b/w AMQP JsonMessageConverter and Spring MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-amqp

Can anyone please tell me what is the difference between

`org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter`

and

`org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`?

Answer (score 1):

Because they both are really different strategies and are used from different place: the first for AMQP protocol, the second - for HTTP. And, of course, you can't use one instead of another.

Don't mix concerns, please.

Or provide more info what you have in mind or this question is funny.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. I have used JsonMessageConverter for converting Generics into JSON in AMPQ, but its not working. And I came to know that MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter will support generics as well. That is the reason I have posted this query. Do we have any other option where it will support generics as well while converting into JSON?

Comment: Can you show a sample on the matter? Where doesn't it work? Maybe there is need just inject `JavaTypeMapper` to the `JsonMessageConverter`?..

Comment: by setting JavaType as below issue has been resolved.

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  JavaType type = TypeFactory.parametricType(ResponceMessageVO.class,classType);
  converter.setJavaType(type);
  template.setMessageConverter(converter);